# User defined Webapp class loader in Apache Tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, classloader, tomcat9

I have a requirement where I need to load my web application using a custom classloader. From the documentation, I could make out that Webapp class loader handles the loading of class from  /WEB-INF/lib and /WEB-INF/classes. Is there a way to override this class loader with a user-defined?